# Coverflow independent of gallery class on Android

Tags: android, animation, widget, carousel, coverflow

I want to use coverflow widget as shown in image below. It should be independent of gallery class as this class is deprecated. Please suggest quickest and simplest way possible. Also images should get recycled which will avoid OutOfMemoy crashes. Thanks in advance. NOTE : It should be exactly as shown in image.

[image]